# Customize an empty world (layers, mob, villages...)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I am actually trying to create on my server a superflat world like in singleplayer: A layer of grass/dirt, then 3 layers of dirt and nothing but cobble until the end.

The only thing I succeded on doing was the `/mv create WorldName NORMAL -t flat` but I still have villages, some slimes, and the worst: no control over the layers (what if I wanted a desert 5 layers of sand, 20 of cobble...).

There must be an easy way that I am not finding (all I found was a totally empty world with just 1 cube to build around...)

I also tried to create a world on singleplayer and copy the file from `%appdata%/.minecraft` to my server folder, but ended up with a strange (but fun) world...

Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Minecraft server (minecraft.net/download) then it should be fairly easy. Make a new single player world, then click *More World Options*. If you don't want villages, uncheck *Generate Structures*. Then click *World Type* once and it should change from default to superflat. Click customize, then presets, and delete all the text and type in this: `3;100*4,3*3,2;1;`. This should make it so it is 1 layer grass, then 3 dirt, then 100 blocks of cobble. Save and quit, close Minecraft and go to your %appdata% folder.

Go to `/.minecraft/saves/(name of superflat world)` and copy that folder. Put it in your server folder and rename it to "world" (replacing the old world and no quote marks). The next time you load the server, it should be that world. I know you tried this but you may have messed up somewhere and I wanted to walk you though this step by step.

Comment: All of this would work, but I don't want to erase my world called "world", because I built a lot of things on it, dungeons, portals and so on, and I was looking to connect my "world" with my "super_flat_new_map" using a portal. 

I know that erasing my "world" would work, all of the tutos I found on YT say the same. Yet I did not find how to create a new world customized and flat.

Comment: You don't have to delete it, you can just move it to your desktop or anywhere other than the server folder.

Comment: If you want to connect them, use MultiVerse plugin and replace a subworld.

Answer (score 2):

Create a map in solo customised to what you need then run that map on your multiplayer server instead of generating the world using the server itself.

I know you tried to run it and it went funny but it is possible and rather easy, watch a tutorial on YouTube because you might have messed something up.

Comment: All the tuto I found are talking about replacing my world called "world" the thing is I am using my world called "world" and I don't want to erase it. 

I am looking to connect my world called "world" with my flat and customized world, using a portal. that's where it gets tricky ^^

Comment: @Niko there may be a way to do it, I'm not 100%, you can definitely using server plugins, I wouldn't know how it would work in vanilla, I wonder if you could list it as your nether world then just disable nether mobs, I have no clue

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the best I found is a pluggin called Cleanroom, easy to use with just a command like the /mv create NAME normal + world options (layers)

http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/cleanroomgenerator/

The last detail to solve is making the slimes get out of the world, but it's a start :)

Comment: And finally, in order to close this topic: 
how to kill the slimes:
create an infinite redstone loop that triggers a command block with a command to kill the slimes: 
command block: /give NAME minecraft:command_block 1
command: /mv purge FLAT-MAP-NAME SLIME

This if you want to spawn other monsters. If you don't, just go into Multiverse-Core file / worlds.yml and change

monsters:
spawn: true

to false

(or enven, change to peaceful mode).

Anyway with all that you can have your custom flat world without ereasing your world called "world" and repeat it again & again. Enjoy!